# Transfer reviews from one product to another

Tags: review, transfer

I've had 10 products which are almost identical except diameter so I've added a configurable product and it's working just fine. 
Downside: existing reviews of the old products are lost. Is there a way to transfer reviews from the old to the new product

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you have using ***Magento 1.x version***.

There are tricky ways,you can do.

Magento, save product id for **review model** at **review** table at `entity_pk_value` column.

So if ***you have to change product ids*** at their  it will work.

### But note that :

you should select those products then which ids is getter than 0 (gt>1
)

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `review` 
WHERE entity_pk_value >0
ORDER BY  `review`.`entity_pk_value`
```

Comment: hmmm...this kind of works...the issue comes if you display the review count and review summary. Those need to be moved too. I havent found a way yet.

Answer (score 1):

Found and tested a guide.

There are 2 steps below:

Query (test on your development machine first):

- update review set entity_pk_value = NEWPRODUCT_ID where
  entity_pk_value = OLDPRODUCT_ID;
- update rating_option_vote set entity_pk_value = NEWPRODUCT_ID where entity_pk_value = OLDPRODUCT_ID;
- update rating_option_vote_aggregated set entity_pk_value = NEWPRODUCT_ID where entity_pk_value = OLDPRODUCT_ID;
- UPDATE review_entity_summary SET `entity_pk_value` = 'NEWPRODUCT_ID ' WHERE
  `entity_pk_value` = OLDPRODUCT_ID;

Then you go to that affected review in admin section and save it.

Resource from: 
https://www.silvatechsolutions.com/tech-tips/moving-reviews-one-product-another-magento/

Also tested on development + production environment.